# Run GUI application in MacOS 10 in Docker

Tags: xquartz, docker

I'd like to run an application in a Docker container that can start a GUI. [This guide](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/) recommends using XQuartz. After starting XQuartz, run the following:

```
ip=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
xhost + $ip
docker run -d --name firefox -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix jess/firefox
```

This gives your local device permission to access the host server. Running the above, I get the error:

```
cannot connect to X server 10.0.0.69:0
```

Comment: Please expand on what you are doing and what you have tried to fix the problem. Your question is far too brief in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not using the right display number. The guide above uses the default display number `:0`.

Find the correct one by running:

```
  display_number=`ps -ef | grep "Xquartz :\d" | grep -v xinit | awk '{ print $9; }'`
```

Then change your docker run command to include the flags:

```
-e DISPLAY=$ip:$display_number \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
```